# How to get name with LUA expression from path

Tags: lua

I have a string below

```
local x = "/archive/testing_Android.Users activity.log"

local name = x:match"^.+/(.+).log$":gsub('%testing_=', '')

print(name)
```

it returns testing_Android.Users activity while i want to get only **Android.Users activity** How can i achieve that?

Comment: Replace `%testing_=` with `^testing_`

Comment: `%testing_=` does not match as there is no `=` in that string.  also why capture a string and delete parts of it? why not capture what you need right away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
local x = "/archive/testing_Android.Users activity.log"

local name = x:match"/testing_(.*).log"
print(name)
```

Comment: That looks good, i have one quick question if i have `START SUITE: Web.Move Users [ ]` from here hoe can i get out put as `Web.Move Users`

Comment: I suggest you read the manual. it contains all the pattern bricks you need. capture anything that is preceded by `: ` and followed by ` [` and make sure you escape any magic characters like `[` using `%`